# Why fusion charts still require adobe flash player

Tags: php, fusioncharts

I got the source code of an app to do some investigation and to figure out how can I convert it's flash based chart to some nice javascript based chart.

When I looked through the app I understand it is using FusionCharts Suite XT v3.6.0. When I read through the web, I understand fusioncharts have deprecated flash based version and now fully javascript based. But I wonder when I try to run a chart in the app, it still ask me to enable flash. any idea why fusion charts still needs a flash player installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

FusionCharts renders in pure javascript form ver 3.4, you can download the latest version 3.13.1 which has got more improved performance and nice features, also it does not require to enable flash while rendering charts in mobile, you can integrate FusionCharts seamlessly on android, ios and also integrate into a hybrid app framework like Ionic.